# Generic interface implementation not working

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

My interface is:

```
public interface SalesForceRecordService<T extends SalesForceRecord> {

    T update(T record) throws IOException;
}
```

My implimentation class is:

```
public class SalesForceRecordServiceImpl<T extends SalesforceRecordImpl> implements SalesforceRecordService {

  @Override
    public T update(T record) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

}
```

`@Override` gives error, method does not override method from its superclass.

I can't able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: You might be getting error since you have not used generics in your implementing interface SalesForceRecordService.
You can write something like this to resolve your error:
public class SalesForceRecordServiceImpl<T extends SalesForceRecord> implements SalesForceRecordService<T> {

 @Override
 public T update(T record) throws IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }


}

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a type to the super class because it expects one. If you want your `SalesForceRecordServiceImpl` to also be generic like you posted, then pass the `T` to `SalesForceRecordService`.

Try this:

```
public class SalesForceRecordServiceImpl<T extends SalesForceRecordImpl>
        implements SalesForceRecordService<T> {

    @Override
    public T update(T record) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also judging by its name `SalesForceRecordImpl` looks to me like a concrete implementation, so maybe you just want this:

```
public class SalesForceRecordServiceImpl
        implements SalesForceRecordService<SalesForceRecordImpl> {

    @Override
    public SalesForceRecordImpl update(SalesForceRecordImpl record)
            throws IOException {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly on the implementing class, you should also pass the type template into the interface description. Otherwise the compiler has no way of checking the T supplied on `SalesForceRecordServiceImpl` is compatible with that of `SalesforceRecordService`

```
public class SalesForceRecordServiceImpl<T extends SalesforceRecordImpl> 
  implements SalesforceRecordService<T> {
   ...
```

(I'm assuming SalesforceRecordImpl is a subtype of SalesforceRecord)

Secondly, forcing method to implement an interface using `@Overrides` annotation only available from java 6 onwards, so if you're on java 5 you'll get a compiler error